# Problem assigning value to $scope property (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angularjs code:

```
$scope.service = {}
$scope.editServiceModal = function (param1, param2) {
    $scope.service = { "obj1": param1, "obj2": param2 }
    $("#editModal").modal('show')
}
```

But when i try calling it on the html as `service.param1` and `service.param2` i don't get any value back. i tried printing the service object but all i get is an empty json object.

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" ng-controller="HmoServiceListCtrl">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit {{service.name}} service</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" name="editServiceForm" id="editServiceForm">
                        <div class="row" style=" margin-left: 0px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="newName" class="col-md-3 ">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Service Name" ng-model="service.name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="newPassword" class="col-md-3">Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <ui-select ng-model="service.type_code" required theme="bootstrap">
                                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Type">
                                                <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
                                            </ui-select-match>
                                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item.code as item in (types | filter: $select.search) track by item.code" required>
                                                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                                            </ui-select-choices>
                                        </ui-select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editService()">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ah, the old mistake of mixing Angular and jQuery together. Don't do this. Ever. Angular generates the DOM from data and has no idea about what jQuery is doing. JQuery manipulates the DOM and has no idea about what Angular is doing. Use one or the other, never both together. Otherwise, this kind of problems happen.

Comment: Can you show us the code (HTML) where you call your `editServiceModal`?

Comment: Okay thanks, made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from one of my projects:

```
vm.VersionClick = function () {
    var element = angular.element("#ChangeLog");
    element.modal('show');
}
```

"vm" In this case is the scope, at the top of the file I initialize vm like this:

```
function sidebar($route, config, routes,datacontext, $scope, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
```

Then throughout the page / js file I am able to use "vm." for everything within itself.

Get rid of the jquery stuff and you should be fine.

Best of luck!

Comment: I did this `$("#editModal").modal('show'`) and replaced with  `var element = angular.element("#ChangeLog");
    element.modal('show');` but problem still persists, although modal still pops out.

Comment: do a console.log of your "$scope" after you set "$scope.service" and make sure it looks good. Make sure $scope is actually the right object and not scoped to the modal or something.

Comment: When doing a console.log($scope), you should get a huge object returned with "service" as a property. If it's not in there, or the object is small- then scope isn't what you think it is and you're working within a different object. That's why I do the "vm" trick.

Comment: Yes, i get 'service' as a property of the $scope object.

Comment: does the service object that is shown in the console.log have obj1 and obj2 properties? What's the issue that still remains? Put some debug tags inside your modal and 1 at the top of the page and see if they match. `{{$scope.service.obj1}}` see if that holds a value. If you have that at the top of your page, and another inside the modal. they should both either have a value or not have a value. (match)

Comment: They both don't have any value.

Comment: That means something is wrong with the way they are being set, or my original point: your setting them on a different scope. Have you successfully set other properties and been able to bind them on your screen somewhere? Also: Your missing `;` at the end of your statements. It's not required in js, but its good habit to use them.

Comment: Yes, there's one other property am setting and am seeing it on my screen.

Comment: The code is  not enough, from where he is calling `editservicemodal()` and also the `html code` is not enough too. Can't see the whole picture.